# Formatting of link works in post editor, but not in post itself

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55092646/6221024) a question on Stack Overflow where I included a link to a Wolfram Alpha computation. In the editor, I write the link as:

```
[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k)
```

-and it displays fine. The preview replaces the URL with the text `wolfram alpha`. When I submitted it, the answer itself shows the literal text:

```
[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k)
```

in its formatted state. I suppose this is due to the parenthesis in the URL, but when I added an extra parenthesis, it rendered as

```
wolfram alpha)
```

displaying that extra parenthesis. Regardless, this discrepancy between the editor and displaying the answer itself should be considered a bug in my opinion.

For good measure, lets see how the URL to [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k) behaves here (its displaying fine in the editor, as per the below screenshot):

> [image]

Here's a go at it with the extra parenthesis:

[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k))

Here's how that looks like in the editor:

> [image]

Comment: I am running Firefox Quantum 65.0.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: The screenshots are from the editor. I can reproduce; it doesn't appear to be browser-specific.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog my mistake. I've retracted my comment. I'll leave my system information though just in case there are issues reproducing it for whatever reason.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed with the rollout of CommonMark. (cc @AdamLear)